# Retrieve child nodes info using Jquery based on condition

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery in my project.I have the following xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<details>
   <company>
      <company-name>abc</company-name>
      <employee>
         <employee-name>John</employee-name>
      </employee>
      <employee>
         <employee-name>Steve</employee-name>
      </employee>
   </company>
   <company>
      <company-name>xyz</company-name>
      <employee>
         <employee-name>Robert</employee-name>
      </employee>
      <employee>
         <employee-name>Stephen</employee-name>
      </employee>
   </company>
</details>
```

Now, I want to retrieve the info of the `<company>` whose `<company-name>` is `xyz` including it's all children employees (`<employee>`) under it. I think I have to use `$.parseXML()`. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var exampleString = "xyz"
var employees = $(XMLdata).find("company-name:contains(" + exampleString + ")").nextAll("employee");
$.each(employees, function() {
  console.log($(this).find("employee-name").text())
});
```

Check the Demo below for a working example:

```js
var XMLdata = $.parseXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><details>   <company>      <company-name>abc</company-name>      <employee>         <employee-name>John</employee-name>      </employee>      <employee>         <employee-name>Steve</employee-name>      </employee>   </company>   <company>      <company-name>xyz</company-name>      <employee>         <employee-name>Robert</employee-name>      </employee>      <employee>         <employee-name>Stephen</employee-name>      </employee>   </company></details>');

var exampleString = "xyz"
var employees = $(XMLdata).find("company-name:contains(" + exampleString + ")").nextAll("employee");
$.each(employees, function() {
  console.log($(this).find("employee-name").text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome!! +1 for quick response.

Comment: @Ashok.N No problem, happy to help

Comment: One small question. How to pass a variable(this variable contains the actual string that needs to be matched) to `contains()` for the same  scenario?

Comment: @Ashok.N i'm not following, please specify the scenario

Comment: For example, the string `xyz` is stored in a variable like `var exampleString="xyz"` and Now I want to say `$(XMLdata).find("company-name:contains(exampleString)").nextAll("employee");` Will that work?

Comment: Gotcha!! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `$.parseXML` combined with the `.find()` method.

To find a specific node depending on its text, you can use jQuery `:contains()` selector

```js
const data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><details><company><company-name>abc</company-name><employee><employee-name>John</employee-name></employee><employee><employee-name>Steve</employee-name></employee></company><company><company-name>xyz</company-name><employee><employee-name>Robert</employee-name></employee><employee><employee-name>Stephen</employee-name></employee></company></details>`;

let company = $($.parseXML(data)).find('company-name:contains(xyz)').parent();
console.log('Company: ' + company.find('company-name').text());

company.find('employee').each(function() {
  console.log('Employee: ' + $(this).find('employee-name').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```